# Import error in Django models on importing from another app

Tags: python, django, django-models, import, importerror

I'm having an app called project with the following models.py file (the hastags are put in the code for purpose, so as to nullify the lines of codes)

```
#inside project.models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import signals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt

from crm.models import Project
#from warehouse.models import Warehouse (hastagged for reason)

class UnitItem(models.Model):
    unitname=models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=True)
    symbol=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.unitname)

        super(UnitItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unitname


class BOQItem(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name='boq_project_crm_project')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    code=models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    detail=models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname', related_name='boq_project_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    purchase_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    sales_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    freight_insurance_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.code)

        super(BOQItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.code, self.detail)


    #For Material Request
class EMRItem(models.Model):
    emr_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name='emr_project_crm_project')
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
#warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse,related_name='emr_project_warehouse_warehouse')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="emr"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_emr_number='001'
        last_emr=type(self).objects.filter(emr_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('emr_id').last()

        if last_emr:
            last_emr_number=int(last_emr.emr_id[6:])
            next_emr_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_emr_number + 1)
        self.emr_id=data + today_string + next_emr_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.emr_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()

        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(EMRItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return  '%s %s %s' % (self.emr_id, self.project, self.date)




class EMRLineItem(models.Model):
    emr_no=models.ForeignKey(EMRItem, related_name='emrline_project_project_emr')

    item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem,
                           related_name='emrline_project_project_boqitem')
    suggest_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname', related_name='emrline_project_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)


#For Purchase Order
class POItem(models.Model):
    po_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name='po_project_crm_project')
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
#warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse,related_name='po_project_warehouse_warehouse')


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="po"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_po_number='001'
    last_po=type(self).objects.filter(po_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('po_id').last()
        if last_po:
            last_po_number=int(last_po.po_id[6:])
            next_po_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_po_number + 1)
        self.po_id=data + today_string + next_po_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.po_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()
        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(POItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return  '%s %s %s' % (self.po_id, self.project, self.date)


class POLineItem(models.Model):
    po_no=models.ForeignKey(POItem, related_name='poline_project_project_po')
    item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem, related_name='poline_project_project_boqitem')
    purchase_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname', related_name='poline_project_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)


class Indent(models.Model):
    indent_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='indent_project_crm_project')
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
#warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse,related_name='indent_project_warehouse_warehouse')
    delivery_address=models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="ind"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_indent_number='001'

        last_indent=type(self).objects.filter(
                                          indent_id__startswith=today_string)
                                          .order_by('indent_id').last()

        if last_indent:
            last_indent_number=int(last_indent.indent_id[6:])
            next_indent_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_indent_number + 1)
            self.indent_id=data + today_string + next_indent_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.indent_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()
        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(Indent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class IndentLineItem(models.Model):
    indent_no=models.ForeignKey(Indent, related_name='indentline_project_project_indent')
    item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem, related_name='indentline_project_project_boqitem') 
    unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname', related_name='indentline_project_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)



class SalesInvoice(models.Model):
    invoice_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='salesinvoice_project_crm_project')
    dispatch_by=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lr_no=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    transportner=models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    vehicle_no=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="invc"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_invoice_number='001'
        last_invoice=type(self).objects
                     .filter(invoice_id__startswith=today_string)
                     .order_by('invoice_id').last()

        if last_invoice:
            last_invoice_number=int(last_invoice.invoice_id[6:])
            next_invoice_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_invoice_number + 1)

        self.invoice_id=data + today_string + next_invoice_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.invoice_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()
        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(SalesInvoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class SalesLineItem(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem, related_name='salesline_project_project_boqitem')
    unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname', related_name='salesline_project_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    unit_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

You could see in the code, I'm calling warehouse model from the Warehouse app and this seems to work fine unless the following code comes into play:

```
  #inside warehouse.models.py
  from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import signals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from datetime import datetime

from crm.models import Project
#from project.models import BOQItem, SalesInvoice, UnitItem, POItem (hashed intentionally, to check if the code is working)


class Warehouse(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=150)

#def get_absolute_url(self):
#   return reverse('master_detail', kwargs={'detail':self.slug})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.code)

        super(Warehouse, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('code',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


class AbstractStock(models.Model):
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class InventoryStock(AbstractStock):
    warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, related_name='inventorystock_warehouse_warehouse_warehouse')
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='inventorystock_warehouse_crm_project')
#     inventory=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem,related_name='inventorystock_warehouse_project_boq')


#def get_absolute_url(self):
#   return reverse('master_detail', kwargs={'detail':self.slug})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.code)

        super(Warehouse, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.inventory.code, self.inventory.detail)


class WIPStock(AbstractStock):
    warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, related_name='wipstock_warehouse_warehouse_warehouse')
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='wipstock_warehouse_crm_project')
#          inventory=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem,related_name='wipstock_warehouse_project_boq')

#def get_absolute_url(self):
#   return reverse('master_detail', kwargs={'detail':self.slug})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.code)

        super(Warehouse, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.inventory.code, self.inventory.detail)


class MRN(models.Model):
    mrn_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='mrn_warehouse_crm_project')   
#   invoice_id=models.ForeignKey(POItem,related_name='mrn_warehouse_project_po')
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="mrn"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_mrn_number='001'

        last_mrn=type(self).objects.filter(mrn_id__startswith=today_string)
                 .order_by('mrn_id').last()

        if last_mrn:
            last_mrn_number=int(last_mrn.mrn_id[6:])
            next_mrn_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_mrn_number + 1)

        self.mrn_id=data + today_string + next_mrn_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.mrn_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()

        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(MRN, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mrn_id


class MRNLineItem(models.Model):
#   item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem,related_name='mrnline_warehouse_project_boqitem')
#unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname',     related_name='mrnline_warehouse_project_unit')
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    purchase_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)




class DeliveryChallan(models.Model):
    dc_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='deliverychallan_warehouse_crm_project')
#invoice_id=models.ForeignKey(SalesInvoice,related_name='deliverychallan_warehouse_project_salesinvoice')
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, related_name='deliverychallan_warehouse_warehouse_warehouse')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data="dc"
        today=dt.date.today()
        today_string=today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        next_dc_number='001'

        last_dc=type(self).objects.filter(dc_id__startswith=today_string)
                .order_by('dc_id').last()

        if last_dc:
            last_dc_number=int(last_dc.dc_id[6:])
            next_dc_number='{0:03d}'.format(last_dc_number + 1)

        self.dc_id=data + today_string + next_dc_number

        if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.dc_id)
            self.created_on=timezone.now()
        else:
            self.edited_on=timezone.now()

        super(DeliveryChallan, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dc_id


class DCLineItem(models.Model):              
#item=models.ForeignKey(BOQItem, related_name='dcline_warehouse_project_boqitem') 
#unit_name=models.ForeignKey(UnitItem, to_field ='unitname',related_name='dcline_warehouse_project_unit')     

    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    unit_rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

If I do either of the two (i.e. not both):

1. from projects.models import BOQItem, SalesInvoice, UnitItem, POItem

or

2. from warehouse.models import Warehouse

Its working great.

But if I import both if them (but hastag the codes which are actually using these imported models for foreignkey, so there's no probability of circular reference) then the error being shown is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'POItem'
```

Why is this happening and how can this be solved?

To explain the use case - Ive separate app for sales and warehouse department. Warehouse department creates warehuse object, which is required for creating Materail Request, Purchase Invoice, Indent, which would be created by the sales team.

Now, warehouse app has inventory model which should access the Bill of Quantity (orBoQ) (also called as Bill of Material or BoM) to be created by the sales team , Material Receipt Note model should access BoQ and Purchase Order and Delivery Challan (i.e. list of items to be delivered) should access the BoQ and sales invoice.

How can I solve this issue if Django doesn't allow:
from AppP.models import A,B,C inside AppQ and 
from AppQ.models import X,Y,Z inside app AppP to be used simultaneously?

(I dont see any logic for this to not be allowed)

Thanks a lot for your effort and any solution would be appreciated.

I am a little saddened that I was given a down-vote because of poor indentation. Well,if u do downvote have the courtesy to comment and give reasons and provide an answer to the question (I strongly feel unless a question is off-topic/bad, there shan't be down-votes). This high handedness would never be taken care of by SO and its sad.

Nonetheless awaiting for any solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you have circular imports.  (i.e. module A imports module B, and module B imports module A.)  The best solution is **don't do that**.  Reorganize your modules so that doesn't happen -- you could make a new module C, which A and B can import.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks mate. U c, I have inside app A: from appB.models import X,Y,Z  (X,Y,Z are different models,i.e. classes in itself in Django) and inside app B: from appA.models import A,B,C (like X,Y,Z these are models and are basically classes inside Django). So I'm not directly importing A from B and B from A. Instead, I say I'm importing "C inside A" from B (i.e. in app/module B importing class C of module A) and similarly importing "D inside B" from A (i.e. in app/module A importing class D of module B). How can this me illegitimate

Comment: Doesn't matter.  If you're importing *anything* from module A, whether it's the whole module by `import A`, or just one thing by `from A import X`, that will trigger circular imports.  It's really best to reorganize your modules so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks John. Maybe I need to re-organize. it, Djang should have allowed this, you know. Specially for those cases where the programmer knows what she/he's doing.

Comment: It's not anything to do with Django specifically; that's just how Python works.

Comment: O see John. But thats the point. While I'm double sure there's no circular reference, this is just not the type of barrier python should keep

Answer (score 0):

When you would like to use it as a ForeignKey in Django you could do this:

```
po_item= models.Foreignkey("project.POItem", related_name="foos")
```

You have to use the full name and put them in quotes.
This way you do not have to import the class at the top of the python file.

Comment: Hi Johan!! Thanks Mate for your reply!! But this is not working. First I tried as u said and the error is foreignkey  object has no attribute "POItem" and then, logically, when I did project.models.POItem, the error is foreignkey object has no attribute "models"